# Offscreen render with QOffscreenSurface using Docker

Tags: qt, opengl, rendering, pybind11

I am using Qt5 for off-screen rendering and have a segmentation fault when running inside Docker.

I have the code inside a `c++` and calling the function via `python` using `pybind11`

This is the code causing the segfault

```
QSurfaceFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion(3, 3);
glFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
glFormat.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);

surface = new QOffscreenSurface();
surface->setFormat(glFormat);
surface->create(); // <-- Here
```

The exact error is :

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::destroyed(QObject*) to QOffscreenSurface::screenDestroyed(QObject*)
```

I tried to run it via `xvfb-run -a python prg.py` and got the same error

Any pointers to debug this?

A little more context to the issue , the above code works fine if I use it inside main thread wrapped in `QApplication`. This problem occurs only when I move it inside a function so I can call it inside python.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last clue about running outside of the main thread is probably the problem you are running into.

Looking at the docs https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qoffscreensurface.html#details:

> Note: Due to the fact that QOffscreenSurface is backed by a QWindow on
>   some platforms, cross-platform applications must ensure that create()
>   is only called on the main (GUI) thread. The QOffscreenSurface is then
>   safe to be used with makeCurrent() on other threads, but the
>   initialization and destruction must always happen on the main (GUI)
>   thread.

So the solution would probably be to create the surface in the main thread and then just use it like you need it via pybind11.

Comment: I do not have a GUI thread. Any pointers on how to create this with pybind11 calls ?

Comment: GUI thread is just the main thread of your application. You should create your surface there, and then if you want to use it from another thread, call
`bool QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent(QSurface *surface)`.

Comment: But when using pybind, I just link with a function call e.g., in python `import myPackage as p    p.myFunction()`

Comment: I called QApplication inside my pybind function before calling the surface and ran it with xvfb to make ti work.